# Java GroupLayout verify design and alignment help needed

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I am using GroupLayout to construct my frame in Java 7 on Windows 7 (64-bit). Following is the structure of layout that I have used seeing the Oracle example on GroupLayout.

Desired Layout:

```
+------------------------------------------+

|  [Label1] [ComboBox1]                    |

|  [Label2] [TextField1] [Button1]         |

|  [Label3] [TextField2] [Button2]         |

|  [Label4] [ComboBox2]                    |

+------------------------------------------+
```

My design in code:

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
        .addComponent(Label1)
        .addComponent(Label2)
        .addComponent(Label3)
        .addComponent(Label4)
    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
        .addComponent(ComboBox1)
        .addComponent(TextField1)
        .addComponent(TextField2)
        .addComponent(ComboBox2)                
    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
        .addComponent(Button1)
        .addComponent(Button2)

);

layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, Button1, Button2);

layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE))
            .addComponent(Label1)
            .addComponent(ComboBox1)
    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE))
            .addComponent(Label2)
            .addComponent(TextField1)
            .addComponent(Button1)
    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE))
            .addComponent(Label3)
            .addComponent(TextField2)
            .addComponent(Button2)
    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE))
            .addComponent(Label4)
            .addComponent(ComboBox2)
);
```

I need to get this checked by more experienced person. Currently, this code results in alignment problem with sizes `ComboBox1, ComboBox2` and `TextField2` reduced significantly.

What are your suggestions to remedy this?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Please use code formatting for code, ASCII art, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML. To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd personally avoid `GroupLayout`, its not really meant for hand coding.

I'd use a GridBagLayout instead

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(label1, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
add(comboBox1, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
add(label2, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
add(textField1, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
add(button1, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
add(label3, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
add(textField2, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
add(button2, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
add(label4, gbc);
gbc.gridx++;
add(comboBox2, gbc);
```

Answer (score 2):

For those type of layouts, I would almost always opt for the [`FormLayout` of JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). Of course this is not included in the standard JDK, so not sure whether this is an option for you.

One of the main benefits (imo) of that layout is that it allows to easily align components in columns, with a decent and controllable resize behavior.